# MongoBD Compass querySrv ENODATA _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.yqxra.gcp.mongodb.net

Tags: mongodb

guy I'm many try. connect MongoDB atlas with MongoDB compass.

[image]

and in network access, i add IP address already

[image]

and wait 1 or 2 weeks it does not work.

same node js

**[failed] task  Error: querySrv ENODATA _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.yqxra.gcp.mongodb.net**

Answer (score 0):

Either DNS resolution is not working correctly on your computer or your cluster is misconfigured by Atlas. Try creating another cluster or accessing the existing one from another computer (with another operating system would be even more helpful).

Alternatively, in the same place where you got the SRV URI there is the option of getting a "legacy" URI for older clients, try that one.

Comment: I try another computer, it works. But now my computer still not working